# If $x^2+y^2+z^3=2$ defines an implicit function $\phi(y,z)=x$ in a neighborhood of $(1,1,0)$, find $\lim_{t\to1} \frac{\phi(t,t^3-1)-t}{t^2-1}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

We know that $\phi_y=-1$, $\phi_z=0$ thanks to the Implicit Function Theorem. Moreover $\phi \in C^1$ in an environment of $(1,0)$, so $\lim_{t\to 1} \phi(t,t^3-1)=1$. Hence,

$$\lim_{t\to1} \frac{\phi(t,t^3-1)-t}{t^2-1}$$

is an indeterminate form (i.e. "$\frac{0}{0}$"). Since both numerator and denominator are differentiable, we can apply L'Hôpital's Rule.

$$\lim_{t\to1} \frac{\phi(t,t^3-1)-t}{t^2-1} \overset{\text{provided it exists}}= \lim_{t\to1} \frac{\phi'(t,t^3-1)}{2t}$$

But what the heck is $\phi'(t,t^3-1)$?

Comment: Did you forget to use the chain rule? Of course, $\phi'(y,z)$ makes no sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin We define $y=t,z=t^3-1$. Then we compute $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} + 3t^2\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} $. Is this OK? If I apply the Chain Rule and get an expression with only one variable, then I can apply L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: There you go. Of course, you need to evaluate those partial derivatives at the correct point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, we have $\phi(y,z) = \sqrt{2-y^2-z^3}$ on a neighbourhood of $(1,0)$ so

$$\lim_{t\to1} \frac{\phi(t,t^3-1)-t}{t^2-1} = \lim_{t\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{2-t^2-(t^3-1)^3}-t}{t^2-1} \stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=} \lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\frac{-2t-9t^2(t^3-1)}{2\sqrt{2-t^2-(t^3-1)^3}}-1}{2t} = -1$$